# Object Serialization not working

Tags: java, serialization, bukkit

It does everything it needs to do except save and/or load the data. I'm assuming the issue is with the loading even though the try/catch gets no exceptions. The files are created by the plugin but it won't load the data that was supposedly saved when it was closed...

The complete class can be found here: http://pastebin.com/pK3NCPfM

The loading method:

```
    public void getClans(){
        try { 
            // Load the Clans
            FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream("Clans.data");
            ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream (f_in);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, Clan> Clans = (HashMap<String, Clan>) obj_in.readObject();
            obj_in.close();
            getLogger().info("Clans successfully loaded");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().info("Error loading clan files...");
            getLogger().info(e.getMessage());
            } 
    }

    public void getPlayers(){
        try { 
            // Load the players that are in a clan
            FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream("clanPlayers.data");
            ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream (f_in);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> clanPlayers = (HashMap<String, String>) obj_in.readObject();
            obj_in.close();
            getLogger().info("clanPlayers successfully loaded");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().info("Error loading clanPlayer files...");
            getLogger().info(e.getMessage());
            } 
    }
```

UPDATE:
I'm not sure why this will not work. If anyone could help me fix the line in question I should be good to go!

```
    public void getPlayers(){
        try { 
            // Load the players that are in a clan
            FileInputStream f_in = new FileInputStream("clanPlayers.data");
            ObjectInputStream obj_in = new ObjectInputStream (f_in);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            clanPlayers = (HashMap<String, String>) obj_in.readObject(); // Error on this line. 
            //I want the HashTable ClanPlayers to be a copy of the object that was saved
            obj_in.close();
            getLogger().info("clanPlayers successfully loaded");
            } catch (Exception e) {
            getLogger().info("Error loading clanPlayer files...");
            getLogger().info(e.getMessage());
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

These methods don't return anything, and don't initialize any field: only local variables. So they're basically complex noops.

Also, you shouldn't cath Exception. Catch IOException, only if you can really handle the exception at this place. Other wise, let the exception propagate, or transform it into a runeim exception and throw the runtime exception.

Comment: Did you look at the code as a whole or just those two functions? And there are other things that actually work with Clans and clanPlayers.

Without the try catch the program would break if there was an error and that wouldn't be preferred. The only real error that occurs is when the plugin is run for the first time.

Comment: I looked at the code you posted here, so only the two methods. If you want more help, define "not working". What should the code do, and what does it do instead? Also, catching and basically ignoring the exception will make the application break, but only a bit later, and for an obscure reason. I'm pretty sure the program won't work if `clanPlayers` is null. And this code, if an exception occurs, will leave `clanPlayers` as null. So now you'll have to guess why `clanPlayers` is null, instead of having a clear IOException explaining exactly what the problem is and where it comes from.